# Another simple "if-else" form in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

i read somewhere before, there is another way to perform the if-else statement, the code should be similar to this:

```
<?php
  $var = "stackoverflow";
  // Here is the if-else
  if(strlen($var) > 1) ? echo "TRUE" : echo "FALSE";
?>
```

I could only remember something like this, but it doesn't work, anyone knows how to write this 1 line if-else statement in php??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo strlen($var) > 1 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```

or

```
if (strlen($var) > 1) echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE";
```

Comment: Cool. YEah, found it, the first one is the one i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

echo in php not inline operator. for this case need to use opeartor print

```
<?php
  $var = "stackoverflow";
  // Here is the if-else
  strlen($var) > 1 ? print("TRUE") : print("FALSE");
?>
```